# Get the returned JSON(from asp.net webservice) in asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, json, web-services, c#-4.0

I have Following web service which is responsible for reading document and returning Json data ,

```
public string HelloWorld(string FileNamePath)
    {
        object filename = FileNamePath;
        //Initiating Application Class
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass AC = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document();
        object readOnly = false;
        object isVisible = true;
        object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        //Reating the word document and adding it to textbox
        try
        {
            int line = File.ReadAllLines(FileNamePath).Count();
            doc = AC.Documents.Open(ref filename, ref missing, ref readOnly,
                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref isVisible);
            value = Regex.Replace(doc.Content.Text, @"[\r|\n|\t|\u0007]", "");
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }    

    }
```

Working kool . Now I am consuming this web service inside my website . 
in the following manners .

```
WebService.WebService objService = new WebService.WebService();
objService.HelloWorld(strFileUploadedPath + strFileName);
```

But How can I print I mean Get the returned JSON in my website .
It is sure that the service is returning JSON.

Please help me to solve it

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking please? Somewhere you have a "string sRetJSON = objService.HellowWorld(strFileUploadedPath + strFileName); ... (variable naming may be off, I just don't see it declared so I'm not sure what you called it).. And you're trying to get the string into. ... a textbox or something? Or html or what? deserialized into a class?

Comment: @Aaron I got my answer from your question, Interesting , I have not declared yet any Variable which will receive the answer  .. Now declared 
string sRetJSON = objService.HellowWorld(strFileUploadedPath + strFileName);
Response.Write(sRetJSON );

and It started working

Comment: Ah, yes. You must assign the response to something in order to use it :)  Best of luck! *I guess technically you can use it from memory with something like "Console.WriteLine(objService.HellowWorld(strFileUploadedPath + strFileName)); without putting it into a variable, but most times you probably will.

Comment: @Aaron thanks for best wishes , actually I am parsing resume and I will pass this data to function which will help me to get the needed stuff , post this as your answer so It will be useful for another guys like me :)